# Change glyphicon on click, for multiple rows of a table using jQuery/Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Simply put, what I'm trying to do is use one glyphicon when the data table is collapsed, and another when the data table is not collapsed.  I have this working fairly well with this bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-collapse-down glyphicon-collapse-up");
    });
});
</script>
```

This works great when I'm viewing the first 5 results in my table, but if I try to go to a different page, the image no longer changes.  This could also be an issue with my overall code, but I figured I'd check this portion first to see if anyone had any better ideas.  I'm assuming I'm going to need to call back to my function below when changing pages, but my scripting skills are not the best.

Here is the HTML portion of my code:

```
<table id="pluginInfo" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive details-control" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display:none">
<thead>
    <tr class = "info">
        <th>Plugin ID: </th>
        <th>Plugin Name: </th>
        <th>Filename: </th>
        <th>Plugin Type: </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for plugin in plugins %}
        <tr>
            <td><a id="details" href="#{{ plugin.pluginID }}" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></i></a>{{ plugin.pluginID }}</td>
            <td>{{ plugin.pluginname }}</td>
            <td>{{ plugin.filename }}</td>
            <td>{{ plugin.plugin_type }}</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr id="{{ plugin.pluginID }}" class="collapse">
           <td>Hidden data 1</td>
           <td>Hidden data 2</td>
           <td>Hidden data 3</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript solution is probably not working because new rows added to your table won't automatically have your `('.gylphicon').click()` event handler attached to them.

As an alternative, you can get the same result with one line of pure CSS by taking advantage of the fact that Bootstrap Collapse is adding `aria-expanded` attributes to your collapsable anchor.

Try this example:

```css
a[aria-expanded="true"] > .glyphicon-collapse-up:before { content: "\e159"; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="pluginInfo" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive details-control" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="">
<thead>
    <tr class = "info">
        <th>Plugin ID: </th>
        <th>Plugin Name: </th>
        <th>Filename: </th>
        <th>Plugin Type: </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="details" href="#plugin1" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></i></a>{{ plugin.pluginID }}</td>
            <td>{{ plugin.pluginname }}</td>
            <td>{{ plugin.filename }}</td>
            <td>{{ plugin.plugin_type }}</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr id="plugin1" class="collapse">
           <td>Hidden data 1</td>
           <td>Hidden data 2</td>
           <td>Hidden data 3</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Browser compatibility for CSS attribute selectors: http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/

You can find the hex value to use in your CSS `content:` property by searching [bootstrap.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/867e2bef8d9c9b901022899227b306a532f5baf3/dist/css/bootstrap.css) for `.glyphicon-collapse-down`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!  That is exactly what I needed!!  Now I just need to stop my 'hidden row' from showing up as an 'entry' in my table and I'll be finished!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is being attached to all elements that exist in the dom at the time the script is run.

`.on` captures events that bubble up to the element that you attach it too.

Try calling `.on` from an element higher in the dom tree.

Perhaps: `$('#pluginInfo').on('click', '.glyphicon') function () { ... });`